# encrypted password file for the linux

Tags: linux, shell

i am using the redhot linux

i am storing the database username and password in to one text file called as filename.txt.this filenam.txt is a variable in my shell script.

```
filename=/home/oracle/filename.txt
vi filename.txt
auth scott tiger

username=`cat ${filename} | grep auth | awk ' {print $2}'`

password=`cat ${filename} | grep auth | awk ' {print $3}'`
```

i am using  this username and password variables into the my script to connect to the data base.

can any body help me how to encript this text file (filename). so that other persons can't sea the data in it.and also how to use the encrypted text file.

Comment: I presume the last line should be `{print $3}`

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of **it depends** tied up in your question that largely depends on **who will have access to the script and who needs to run it?**.

If it is just you who needs access to the file and you want to keep others from seeing it, then make sure you are the `owner` of the file and just set the file permissions to `0600` so only you have read access to `filename.txt`

If on the other hand you have the script publish in a public place on your box (e.g. /usr/local/bin), and several people need to be able to run the script, you can limit reading of the file to only those that need run the script by creating a common unix `group` and setting ownership to the common group and read permissions to at most `0640` for filename. However, all members of the group will still have read permissions of the file. (no you can't make the file group executable but not readable by the group)

Finally, if you encrypt the file, that brings with it problems of it own.  The script will then either have to (1) prompt for a password, or (2) contain the password itself. That doesn't buy you much, you might as well just let the database prompt for the password and limit dissemination of the password to those that need to run it.

But your question was about encryption, so let's at least take a look. There are a number of facilities available, `pgp`, `openssl`, etc.. Taking `openssl` for example, you can easily encrypt `filename.txt` with:

```
openssl des3 -salt -in filename.txt -out filename.des -pass pass:thepassword
```

or using the `-k` option instead of `-pass`:

```
openssl des3 -salt -in filename.txt -out filename.des -k thepassword
```

**if no password option is specified, you will be prompted for the password**

Decryption works in the same manner simply add the `-d` option and reverse the `-in` and `-out` filenames (make sure you do or you can corrupt the file):

```
openssl des3 -d -salt -in filename.des -out filename.txt -k thepassword
```

Obviously this doesn't buy you much because `thepassword` to `filename.txt` is still visible and can be used to decrypt `filename.txt` by those who have access to the script.

So hiding a credential file from those that need the credentials from the file is no easy task. Now if you search, you may find some key-based scheme that may get you closer, but that isn't something on the tip of my tongue. You are also limited by shell scripts not making use of setuid/setgid to run with other permissions (without creating a large security hole).

Hopefully this helped. There is just no silver-bullet that covers all the possibilities and no easy way to hardcode a password in a script and then prevent read-access to users of the script the way you can, say -- with .htaccess files and a web server.